# Is there a JavaScript undefined property handling like in Angular2 templates

Tags: javascript, angular

I was wondering if there is a neat way of doing this:

```
if (app && app.object && app.object.foo) {
  alert(app.object.foo.bar);
}
```

This is really long and "ugly".

I found out that Angular2 has something really great for cases like this. But I think it's only for templates:

```
<div>{{this?.object?.foo?.bar}}</div>
```

This got me really exited because I have a lot of code that looks just like the first example. It get's the job done but I'm really hopping there is something more sophisticated.

Comment: I would like to note that if any of `app` or `app.object` or `app.object.foo` is  not truthy like number `0` this will return false.

Comment: Just FYI, what you are describing is a feature of TypeScript, not of Angular2. Angular2 (optionally) makes use of TypeScript, which is why you see the feature in the Angular2 documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many languages have this functionality, some call it `safe navigation operator` or even `Elvis operator` (yes haha).

JavaScript does not have this functionality. If you are open to use  `CoffeeScript`, you might take a look at the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators).

But, if you want to keep with JS, you should take a look at [`lodash.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs#get), which lets you do something like this:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// → 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.d.c', 'default');
// → 'default'
```

Comment: Oh. So this is how it's called. Was searching with all other keywords. I do like this approach. I think I will combine this approach with the one from @nikhil-maheshwari. Passing properties as one argument - splitted by the dot (as usual). Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution sometime back on net :

```
function checkNested(obj /*, level1, level2, ... levelN*/) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  obj = obj[args[i]];
 }
  return true;
}

var test = {level1:{level2:{level3:'level3'}} };

checkNested(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'level3'); // true
checkNested(test, 'level1', 'level2', 'foo'); // false
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/kjsxnunp/

Comment: This is also a good approach. It's not as neat as angular's but it's still good.

Comment: I was actually in the similar situation and found this useful !

Comment: I like this, A LOT. No third party scripts or frameworks; just a pure JS function.

Answer (score 3):

not out of the box.

```
var string = function(v){ return v == null? "": String(v) }  //because I usually want this behaviour

var fetch = function(path, obj){
    path instanceof Array || (path = string(path).split('.'));
    for(var i=0, v=obj; i<path.length; v = v[path[i++]])
        if(v == null) return void 0;
    return v;
}
```

and your code:

```
if(fetch("object.foo", app)){
    alert(app.object.foo.bar);
}
```

or even more direct:

```
alert( fetch("object.foo.bar", app) );
//will alert undefined, if the path could not be resolved
```

Argument order is this way around, because this function is usually curried in my code, so I can do sth like:

```
arr.map(fetch('some.deeper.path'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter (than original) way in JavaScript (less readable)

```
if ((a = app) && (o = a.object) && (f = o.foo)) {
  alert(f.bar);
}
```

**The way I'd write it** in CoffeeScript (my preferred method)

```
alert f.bar if f = app?.object?.foo?
```

If you're really into using Javascript and want it to appear clean, you could use something like:

```
function ifExist (name) { // Returns undefined if it doesn't exist
  arr = name.split('.');
  obj = eval('if (typeof '+(x = arr.splice(0,1)[0])+' !== \'undefined\') '+x);
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
      return obj;
    }
    else {
      obj = obj[arr[i]];
    }
  }
  return obj
}

alert(ifExist('app.object.foo.bar'));
```

Because it uses eval, it could pose a security risk if `app.object.foo.bar` is generated by a the user. It works in simple cases (such as the one you posted above), but using something like `app.object['foo'].bar` in it would probably break it without adding some input checks.